# How can I authenticate user for Laravel feature testing?

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-5.5

I am trying to test if authenticated manager will redirect to dashboard. (When the manager is already authenticated and goes to login page, he is redirected to dashboard)

```
public function testIfBackendIsLoggingAuthenticatedUser()
{
    $manager = \App\Manager::where('email', 'test@email.com')->first();
    Auth::attempt(['email' => $manager->email, 'password' => $manager->password]);

    $response = $this->actingAs($manager)
        ->get(route('backend.login.show'))
        ->assertRedirect(route('backend.dashboard.index'));
}
```

But I get the result

```
Response status code [200] is not a redirect status code.
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

How can I make authentication test?

Comment: So are you testing action of *logging in* or that auth/guest middleware works?

Comment: I am trying to test situation when manager who is already logged in tries goes to login page

Comment: Obviously `$manager->password` is hashed and should blow up (in another words not work). Besides that delete line starting with `Auth::` and that should be it.

Comment: there is no need to mess with the guard directly at all ... just call `$this->actingAs(...)` that is what it is for.    Also did you think that perhaps this is following redirects, so it ends up on the dashboard page, which would be a 200 response?

Comment: @lagbox I thank you. Really nothing to do with password hashing. But working version shows redirect, not follows)

Answer (score 0):

The **attempt** method hashed the password itself. You are passing hashed password, so it double hashed the password so it is incorrect.

Use:

```
Auth::login($manager);
```

instead of:

```
Auth::attempt(['email' => $manager->email, 'password' => $manager->password]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, guys. Really the mistake was that I forgot to mention guard. So the working code is

```
$response = $this->actingAs($manager, 'manager')
        ->get(route('backend.login.show'))
        ->assertRedirect(route('backend.dashboard.index'));
```